# Исмаил-Бей — склонение микрорайона без родового слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, склонение, топонимика

Есть микрорайон Исмаил-Бей.
«Старушка из Исмаил-Бея» или «Старушка из Исмаил-Бей» — как правильно написать название статьи?

Answer (score 3):

1. Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями *город, село, деревня, хутор, река* и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное наименование.
2. В «Словаре географических названий» А. В. Суперанской (М., 2013) указано, что **топонимы обычно не склоняются** в сочетании со следующими географическим терминами: *болото, бухта, горы, государство, долина, залив, застава, земля* (как административно-территориальная единица), *кишлак, ключ, колодец, королевство, местечко, месторождение, мыс, область, озеро, округ, остров, перевал, плато, плоскогорье, плотина, площадь, полуостров, поселок, провинция, пролив, промысел, **район*** (как административно-территориальная единица), *селение, станция, урочище, хребет, штат.*
3. Если сложносоставной топоним представляет собой русское или давно освоенное название, в косвенных падежных формах его первая часть должна склоняться: *из Камня-Каширского, в Переславле-Залесском, в Могилеве-Подольском, в Ростове-на-Дону.*

Обобщаем:
топоним нерусского и неславянского происхождения, малоизвестный, поэтому с родовым словом "район" **не склоняем**, без родового слова — склоняем только **вторую часть**.

Я бы написала так:
в Исмаил-Бее, жители Исмаил-Бея, **«Старушка из Исмаил-Бея»**;
в районе Исмаил-Бей, жители района Исмаил-Бей.

[Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

Answer (score 0):

Есть примеры склонения из wiki и wikimapia:

> Сюжет «Измаил-Бея» в известной степени связан с... биографией
> кабардинского князя Измаил-Бея Атажукина.   В «Измаил-Бее»
> неоднократно встречается приём рассказа в рассказе.
>
> История Исмаил-бея началась с палаточного городка...